# Building flink from source---error of resolving dependencies

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying to build Apache Flink from the source. I am strictly following 
the instructions given @github flink page. https://github.com/apache/flink

I am facing the error for resolving the dependencies for project 
`flink-mapr-fs`.

Firstly, I tried using latest maven, and afterward, as per instruction at 
the flink github page  https://github.com/apache/flink
https://github.com/apache/flink , I also tried via `maven 3.1.1`, but the 
same error.

In addition, I tried for `flink 1.8.0` and `1.7.2` as well but the same problem exist. The detail of error is as below:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project flink-mapr-fs: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.flink:flink-mapr-fs:jar:1.7.2: Could not transfer artifact com.mapr.hadoop:maprfs:jar:5.2.1-mapr from/to mapr-releases (http://repository.mapr.com/maven/): GET request of: com/mapr/hadoop/maprfs/5.2.1-mapr/maprfs-5.2.1-mapr.jar from mapr-releases failed: Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 49411916; received: 39845888 -> [Help 1]
```